# How to regenerate autoloader per local changes to package composer.json

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I know this is sloppy and unconventional, but I need to test some changes to a package by manually adjusting a composer.json file within a package in the vendor folder. But I can't figure out how to get the new dependencies and "autoloader->file" changes to take hold. I've tried `composer install`, `composer dumpautoload -o`, and installing directly from that folder (which merely created a new and useless "vendor" folder within the package directory).

Is this even possible, or just too sloppy for Composer to offer a way to go about it?